# Problems bringing in latest record with MAX(date)

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, max

So I haven't had this happen before and am fairly familiar with the MAX function. My result set is still showing duplicates for certain values but not for others.

Table `A`:

```
ID  Height       DateTimePerformed
1   {170.18|67}  9/14/2013
1   {170.18|67}  9/12/2013
1   {170.18|67}  9/13/2013
2   {182.88|72}  1/13/2014
2   {182.88|72}  9/30/2013
2   {1889.76|744}    9/1/2013
2   {182.88|72} 10/21/2013
2   {182.88|72}  1/20/2014
2   {182.88|72}   3/3/2014
2   {182.88|72}  1/27/2014
2   {182.88|72}   2/3/2014
2   {182.88|72}  2/10/2014
2   {182.88|72}  12/2/2013
2   {182.88|72}   9/4/2013
2   {182.88|72} 11/18/2013
2   {182.88|72}  9/16/2013
2   {182.88|72}  10/7/2013
2   {182.88|72} 12/23/2013
2   {182.88|72}  2/17/2014
```

Query/Statement:

```
SELECT
*
FROM A
 JOIN (
    SELECT VisitID,Height,MAX(DateTimePerformed) AS 'MaxDateTimePerformed'
    FROM A
    GROUP BY VisitID,Height
    ) AS B
        ON A.VisitID=B.VisitID
            AND A.DateTimePerformed=B.MaxDateTimePerformed
```

Results:

```
ID  Height          DateTimePerformed
1   {170.18|67}     9/14/2013
2   {1889.76|744}   9/1/2013
2   {182.88|72}     3/3/2014
```

Comment: You are grouping by VisitID,Height. This means that each unique combination of those two columns will be in your result set. and looking at the data this is correct (ID 2 has two different Heights!). How do you want to see the data? please update your question with your expected result

Comment: I'd like to see the ID and the Height that was recorded LAST.

Comment: I can see no dates here. Also, it's not usually a good idea to store two values in one column. In this case, just store inches OR cms, and calculate the missing value either in your query or in your presentation layer, e.g. with a bit of PHP or javascript. Finally, I know almost nothing about M$SQL, but isn't this an opportunity for 'window' functions?

Comment: Unfortunately, Strawberry, I don't determine how our end users input their data and they need to see both in the end result set. But I know what you mean... it bugs me.

Comment: So, you're not in control of the data base? Weird.

Comment: I'm a Report Writer not a DBA (although it'd be fun to be). Even then it wouldn't be up to me it's the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I have created a SqlFiddle for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a4a7/4)

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID,MAX(DateTimePerformed) AS 'MaxDateTimePerformed'
              FROM A
              GROUP BY ID
            ) AS B
            ON A.ID=B.ID
 AND A.DateTimePerformed=B.MaxDateTimePerformed
 Order by A.ID ASC
```

Comment: My answer was just based on the data examples OP posted. There is no explanation of how the Height data is formed. One would expect that that "{182.88|72" is the height in centimeters and some other measurement that correlate. Therefore your assertion that 182.88 can be both 72 or 73 looks shaky. Best to base the answer on what the OP has provided than guess.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. This should work for our data as each ID should only have one timestamp (the datetime type includes everything) so joining on both should do it!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to up vote if you think useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the result you want is:

```
VisitID Height      DateTimePerformed
2       {182.88|72} 2014-03-03
1       {170.18|67} 2013-09-14
```

Then all you need to do is remove `height` from the select and group by clause in the derived table.

```
SELECT 
    A.*
FROM 
    A
JOIN (
    SELECT VisitID,MAX(DateTimePerformed) AS 'MaxDateTimePerformed'
    FROM A
    GROUP BY VisitID
) AS B
  ON A.VisitID=B.VisitID
 AND A.DateTimePerformed=B.MaxDateTimePerformed;
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes like this:
if you query

```
SELECT Height, MAX(DateTimePerformed) AS 'MaxDateTimePerformed'
```

then you will get the highest date value in the query. It will return one row.

If you query

```
SELECT VisitID,Height,MAX(DateTimePerformed) AS 'MaxDateTimePerformed'
```

you will get The highest date value for each Height, but by adding and grouping by VisitID, you will get a row returned for each single unique VisitID (you are grouping by VisitID - therefore one) - hence different Height rows with the same VisitID will return the number of unique Height under the same VisitID.

You need a subquery to get the max date value compared to one column, and then use those values by self joining the result from the subquery in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function ROW_NUMBER() to select only one row per id by specific MAX/MIN criteria by using ORDER BY inside. As example:

```
SELECT B.* FROM
   (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DateTimePerformed DESC) AS RN, a.* 
    FROM A a
   ) AS B
WHERE B.RN=1
 Order by B.ID ASC
```

In this example, you'll have only one record with the max date for each ID. In a case of more than one record with the same date for a same ID only one will be returned.

In addition, you can specify ORDER BY DateTimePerformed DESC, Height DESC in OVER clause to select record with max both of DateTimePerformed and Height.

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3257/1)